# Ограничить прямой доступ к JSP странице(Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Необходимо запретить пользователю прямой доступ(доступ по url из браузера) к jsp страницам. При этом мои страницы лежат в папке WEB-INF/view и все равно прописав url я получаю страницу любую.

*Как ограничить прямой доступ?*

Comment: Тоесть вам нужно например `gu.ru` и чтобы нельзя было набрать другой урл а только дописывать?

Comment: @Flippy, нужно, чтобы к примеру: пользователь со своей страницы *hotel/user* не смог перейти на страницу админа, набрав *hotel/admin*

Comment: Устанавливайте настройки Security, куча манов есть по его использованию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два способа. Первый - это вообще не использовать url'ы типа `/home/<username>`, а использовать вместо них просто `/home`, на который повесить контроллер, отдающий контент только для текущего пользователя. Второй - возвращать ошибку [HTTP 403](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#403) для пользователей не прошедших проверку и перенаправлять на форму логина или возвращать [HTTP 401](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#401) для неавторизованных пользователей. С помощью [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) это можно сделать так:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("authentication.name == #userName")
    public String userHome(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, Model uiModel) {
        return "user_home";
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 Что значит *отдающий контент только для текущего пользователя ? 2 Не прошедших проверку* - какую проверку и где определять, кто какую роль имеет?

Comment: Я же привёл вам пример кода, в котором Spring Security с помощью аннотации `@PreAuthorize` проверяет соответствие имени текущего пользователя имени переданному в `@PathVariable`.

Comment: как это решает проблему??? Что даст эта проверка??? Есть контроллер, который возвращает страницу, контроллер замаплен на url. Знаю url я могу получить любую страницу - это надо запретить

Comment: Если пользователь bsuart попытается открыть `/home/admin`, он получит ошибку http 403. Если пользователь admin попытается открыть ту же ссылку, она откроется. Если неавторизованный пользователь попытается получить доступ к этой странице, он будет отравлен на страницу с формой логина. Что вам ещё надо?

Comment: Да, это и надо. Теперь как bsuart установить роль пользователя, admin роль администратора?

Comment: Приведённый мной код ориентируется только на имя пользователя, роли устанавливать не надо. Если вам нужно разграничение доступа по ролям, то аннотацию надо изменить на `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")`. Сам же процесс назначение ролей пользователям зависит от того, какой authentication provider используется.

Comment: я так понимаю роль пользователю устанавливается на время сессии?

Comment: Грубо говоря, да. Есть ещё remember me пользователи, у которых авторизация прозрачно восстанавливается после истечения сессии, но это уже тонкости.